# How do I not show_source on an included file?

Tags: php

I have a file that calls a set of functions `utils.php`, however when I include it, my show_source function includes the source of the included file. I tried putting the function file in a parent folder, but even calling..

```
include("../includes/utils.php");
```

Still shows the source of the file. How do I disable the source for any included files? Thanks in advanced!

Edit: I found out why it was showing the source, it was some weird PHP issue my school has.. sorry for the confusion as well, but showing the source was a parameter of the assignment

Comment: Why are you running `show_source`?

Comment: What is the purpose of 'my_show_source function? The name implies that is there to show the source. Add the function code to stop guessing.

Comment: It's a parameter of my homework, we have to show the source of the files. But I don't want my included file shown on EVERY page -- just when linked to it.

Comment: btw, if I'm asking a question about a show_source isn't it obvious I have a reason for using it? Jeez..

Comment: @PRPGFerret - no, it's not obvious. Which is why we ask questions. You gave an extremely brief description of your problem with no code that would help us help you. Never assume anything is obvious to others here, especially when you're not giving enough details to answer your question.

Comment: Well then how can I clarify? Moving the file to a parent directory didn't work, neither did moving it to a child directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to `show_source` (for whatever reason, in this case it's required) but leave out the source of included files, BUT you have to show the source of the included file if it is linked to...

```
<?php
function test($param) {
    //do something
}

if ($_GET['show_source'] == "true") {
    show_source(__FILE__);
}
```

and to link to it..

```
<a href='../includes/utils.php?show_source=true'>Show Source of Utils.php</a>
```

I'm not sure if this helps everybody, but it's how I solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The source of files should never be displayed with include() or require(). If PHP is not installed correctly on your server you might get this problem. Another common problem is you did not put the PHP open and close tags around your code.

Make sure you have your open and close tags:

```
<?php
//Your code here
?>
```

Comment: close tags shall be avoided as often as possible

Comment: It's not my server, it's a university server so I can't access the ini.php file